# A Colorful Clock With CSS & jQuery with real time of the server, not cliets time,how do this?

Tags: jquery, clock

I made a clock using this jQuery Tutorial:

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/12/colorful-clock-jquery-css/

But this watch takes time of client, I would use this jQuery to get the server time, how I can do this getting the server time?

---

edit:

the script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/* This code is executed after the DOM has been completely loaded */

$('#fancyClock').tzineClock();

});
```

the jquery.tzineClock.js

```
(function($){

// A global array used by the functions of the plug-in:
var gVars = {};

// Extending the jQuery core:
$.fn.tzineClock = function(opts){

    // "this" contains the elements that were selected when calling the plugin: $('elements').tzineClock();
    // If the selector returned more than one element, use the first one:

    var container = this.eq(0);

    if(!container)
    {
        try{
            console.log("Invalid selector!");
        } catch(e){}

        return false;
    }

    if(!opts) opts = {}; 

    var defaults = {
        /* Additional options will be added in future versions of the plugin. */
    };

    /* Merging the provided options with the default ones (will be used in future versions of the plugin): */
    $.each(defaults,function(k,v){
        opts[k] = opts[k] || defaults[k];
    })

    // Calling the setUp function and passing the container,
    // will be available to the setUp function as "this":
    setUp.call(container);

    return this;
}

function setUp()
{
    // The colors of the dials:
    var colors = ['orange','blue','green'];

    var tmp;

    for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        // Creating a new element and setting the color as a class name:

        tmp = $('<div>').attr('class',colors[i]+' clock').html(
            '<div class="display"></div>'+

            '<div class="front left"></div>'+

            '<div class="rotate left">'+
                '<div class="bg left"></div>'+
            '</div>'+

            '<div class="rotate right">'+
                '<div class="bg right"></div>'+
            '</div>'
        );

        // Appending to the container:
        $(this).append(tmp);

        // Assigning some of the elements as variables for speed:
        tmp.rotateLeft = tmp.find('.rotate.left');
        tmp.rotateRight = tmp.find('.rotate.right');
        tmp.display = tmp.find('.display');

        // Adding the dial as a global variable. Will be available as gVars.colorName
        gVars[colors[i]] = tmp;
    }

    // Setting up a interval, executed every 1000 milliseconds:
    setInterval(function(){

        var currentTime = new Date();
        var h = currentTime.getHours();
        var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var s = currentTime.getSeconds();

        animation(gVars.green, s, 60);
        animation(gVars.blue, m, 60);
        animation(gVars.orange, h, 24);

    },1000);
}

function animation(clock, current, total)
{
    // Calculating the current angle:
    var angle = (360/total)*(current+1);

    var element;

    if(current==0)
    {
        // Hiding the right half of the background:
        clock.rotateRight.hide();

        // Resetting the rotation of the left part:
        rotateElement(clock.rotateLeft,0);
    }

    if(angle<=180)
    {
        // The left part is rotated, and the right is currently hidden:
        element = clock.rotateLeft;
    }
    else
    {
        // The first part of the rotation has completed, so we start rotating the right part:
        clock.rotateRight.show();
        clock.rotateLeft.show();

        rotateElement(clock.rotateLeft,180);

        element = clock.rotateRight;
        angle = angle-180;
    }

    rotateElement(element,angle);

    // Setting the text inside of the display element, inserting a leading zero if needed:
    clock.display.html(current<10?'0'+current:current);
}

function rotateElement(element,angle)
{
    // Rotating the element, depending on the browser:
    var rotate = 'rotate('+angle+'deg)';

    if(element.css('MozTransform')!=undefined)
        element.css('MozTransform',rotate);

    else if(element.css('WebkitTransform')!=undefined)
        element.css('WebkitTransform',rotate);

    // A version for internet explorer using filters, works but is a bit buggy (no surprise here):
    else if(element.css("filter")!=undefined)
    {
        var cos = Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 / 360 * angle);
        var sin = Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 / 360 * angle);

        element.css("filter","progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11="+cos+",M12=-"+sin+",M21="+sin+",M22="+cos+",SizingMethod='auto expand',FilterType='nearest neighbor')");

        element.css("left",-Math.floor((element.width()-50)/2));
        element.css("top",-Math.floor((element.height()-50)/2));
    }

}

})(jQuery)
```

What I need change in each .js to get the server time?
Sorry but I begin in jQuery a few week ago, I'm learning yet, I don't know how can change great things in a jQuery.

---

Edit:

I wrote the

Dear MarZab, I do what you say, but it doesn't work, instead of the time appear "NaN" in hour, and the same in minute and seconds.

I wrote:

```
            var clienttime = new Date();
            var servertime = 1368597301000; // *mili*seconds
            // snip
            setInterval(function () {
                var currentTime = new Date();
                currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + servertime.time - clienttime.time);

                var h = currentTime.getHours();
                var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
                var s = currentTime.getSeconds();

                animation(gVars.green, s, 60);
                animation(gVars.blue, m, 60);
                animation(gVars.orange, h, 24);

            }, 1000);
```

So I try to put the

```
            var clienttime = new Date();
            var servertime = 1368597301000; // *mili*seconds
```

Inside of function, but even this way doesn't work.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready(function ()         {
            setInterval(function ()
            {
                var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
                var sdegree = seconds * 6;
                var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
                $("#sec").css({ "-moz-transform": srotate, "-webkit-transform": srotate });
            }, 1000);
            setInterval(function ()
            {
                var hours = new Date().getHours();
                var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
                var hdegree = hours * 30 + (mins / 2);
                var hrotate = "rotate(" + hdegree + "deg)";
                $("#hour").css({ "-moz-transform": hrotate, "-webkit-transform": hrotate });

```
        }, 1000);
        setInterval(function ()
         {
            var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
            var mdegree = mins * 6;
            var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";
            $("#min").css({ "-moz-transform": mrotate, "-webkit-transform": mrotate });
        }, 1000);
    });    
</script>
```

for full description check http://asp-net-by-parijat.blogspot.in/2014/09/aspnet-digital-clock-with-jquery-css3.html

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the time via php/asp etc. It wont be perfectly synced because of the transport/render delay but most of the time that works fine.

Then use the variable and compare it to the local time.

```
var clienttime = new Date();
var servertime = 1368597301000; // *mili*seconds
// snip
setInterval(function(){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime()+servertime.time-clienttime.time);
```

Comment: Dear MarZab thanks! But i dont know how do this.
Please help, i have this archives:
In my aspx page i have the scripts arqchives link to .js


I use the .js, what i need change in my .js do get the servertime in each page?
regards

Comment: you need to change the code of setinterval as above then on every page you want this clock you need to print out the servertime as above. I cant really help you any further.

Comment: Dear MarZab, i do what you say, but dont work, instead of the time appear "NaN" in hour, and the same in minute and seconds.